# How to use Redis Search in a Redis Cluster?

Tags: redis, redis-cluster, redis-search

I have a 6 node Redis cluster - with 3 masters and 3 replicas.

I connected on Master1 (M1) and created an index through redis-cli.

It redirected me to M2 on which the index got created.

Now, I inserted some 5-10 records satisfying the index key pattern and all of them got distributed on M1, M2 or M2. Then, I tried to run a redis search using the created index and it is only returning the JSONs that got inserted in M2 (the master on which index got created).

Even when I am manually connecting to the different master like M1 or M3, even though there are JSONs on those masters, I am still being redirected to M2 and the result set is only the JSONs that got inserted in M2.

Is this a normal behaviour? If yes, then how do I implement a Redis search feature in a cluster?

PS: All of these observation is through redis-cli.